# How to move a set of files on the same FTP server?

Tags: command-line-interface, ftp

On the remote FTP server, I have a set of files in the directory `remote.dir1`. I would like to move all the files in that directory to `remote.dir2`.

I am using `lftp` and was trying something like this:

```
lftp> mv remote.dir1/* remote.dir2/
```

It does not work and displays: `Access failed: 550 remote.dir1/*: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

I also tried:

```
lftp> glob -a mv remote.dir1/* remote.dir2/
```

which displays the usage message: `Usage: mv <file1> <file2>`

However, moving single file works: `lftp> mv remote.dir1/file1 remote.dir2/`

As a last resort, we can construct a file containing a set of lftp `mv` commands and `source` it.
Are there any solutions I am not aware of?
Or, are there any capable command line tools for the task?

Edit:
I am restricted to FTP environment, so only solutions using FTP are acceptable due to the environmental constraint.

Comment: When you say 'it does not work' are you getting any errors?

Comment: yes, in this particular case i'm using `lftp`, it throws me this line: `Access failed: 550 remote.dir1/*: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*For documentation purpose, I will post the steps I used to complete the task. Any better solutions are much appreciated. ;-)*

**Note**: this solution uses the `lftp` FTP client. You may have to install it on your machine before you can proceed.

Solution:

```
lftp> renlist remote.dir1/ | "sed 's/\(.*\)/mv \"\1\" \"remote.dir2\/\"/'" > list  
lftp> source list  
lftp> !rm list
```

Or, the *one-liner<sup>TM</sup>*:

```
lftp> renlist remote.dir1/ | "sed 's/\(.*\)/mv \"\1\" \"remote.dir2\/\"/'" > list && source list && !rm list
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears that lftp only supports the `glob` syntax with commands accepting a single argument, so `mv`, which requires two, is out.

With FTP, your server *might* allow for extended commands, especially the execution of a limited command set via `SITE EXEC` or similar means - check the FTP server's documentation, its help (`SITE HELP`) or the login banner. These however are not standardized, so if the solution needs to be FTP-server-agnostic, scripting based on the output of the file list seems like the best idea.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but in July 2017 the "mmv" command was added to lftp.

```
Usage: mmv [OPTS] <files> <target-dir>
Move <files> to <target-directory> with wildcard expansion
 -O <dir>  specifies the target directory (alternative way)
```

So, in your case:

```
mmv remote.dir1/* remote.dir2/
```

Answer (score 0):

rsync is great for moving files from one machine to another (or even between the same machine).

```
rsync -avz -e "ssh -i /key/path/key.rsa" user@1.2.3.4:/path/on/remote/server/ /path/on/local/server
```

This command supplies a private key, and connects to a machine. It grabs files from the remote directory, and copies them to the local directory. You can also do the reverse of this by switching the source and destination.

Comment: The question is about using *an FTP client* to move a server directory's files

Comment: OP also stated: "Are there any solutions I am not aware of?
Or, are there any capable command line tools for the task?". rsync sounds pretty capable to me.

Comment: The question is about moving files. OP happened to try FTP but that's not the only way.

Comment: @DrewKhoury Sorry for not being clear enough. I am restricted to FTP protocol only. One of reasons is because the FTP server is a Windows machine. I will update the question on that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by [cychoi](https://serverfault.com/a/532542/260497) is for an interactive session. I was able to make use of it in a shell script (Bash 4.2.46, lftp 4.4.8-14.el7_9, CentOS 7.6.1810). Essentially:

```
local flist=files.txt
local cmds=cmds.txt
cd ${WORK_DIR}
LFTP_PASSWORD=${SFTP_PASSWORD} \
lftp --env-password -u ${SFTP_USER} sftp://${SFTP_HOST}/ << EOF
nlist ${SRC_DIR} > $flist
!cat $flist | grep -v "^\." | sed "s|\(.*\)|mv ${SRC_DIR}/\1 ${DST_DIR}/|" > $cmds
source $cmds
EOF
```

Where, the script's variables had the following meanings:

- **WORK_DIR** The work directory for the script to create intermediate files. The files `files.txt` and `cmds.txt` get created inside this directory.
- **SFTP_HOST** SFTP server IP address or hostname.
- **SFTP_USER**, **SFTP_PASSWORD** SFTP user and password used to connect to the server.
- **SRC_DIR** Source directory on the SFTP server. All files residing on this directory had to be moved.
- **DST_DIR** Destination directory on the SFTP server. Files were moved to this directory.

Answer (score -1):

I thought FTP was more or less dead.  It's been close to 5 years since I've used it, and it was on the way out 10 years ago.

That said, I always found the ncftp family of command line tools very friendly, and I expect this would "just work".

I'm not going to set up an FTP server for the purposes of verifying this, but give it a try.  There's a lot else to like about ncftp (At least from version 2 on).